# How do I resolve the tkinter "pyimage4" error for a function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing an application which has a function that takes the frames captured from a camera and feeds it to a window every 15 ms, and another function that takes the image from the first function, crops the image, and feeds it to a separate window every 1500 ms. The two functions run simultaneously via the `multiprocessing` package

The code is as such:

```
# Imports
from multiprocessing import Process 
import tkinter as tk
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk

from .VideoCapture_old import VideoCapture # video feed func
from .Plots import Plots # image crop function

# Application
class App:
    def __init__(self):

        # Initialising live stream window
        self.stream_window = tk.Tk()
        self.live_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.stream_window)
        self.live_canvas.pack()

        # Initialising window for cropped screen
        self.analyse_window = tk.Tk()
        self.crop_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.analyse_window)
        self.crop_canvas.pack()

        # Initialise camera
        self.vid = VideoCapture() #secondary script not shown here

        # Initialise cropping function
        self.plot = Plots() #secondary script not shown here

        # Setting up multiprocessing
        p1 = Process(target=self.update_feed())
        p2 = Process(target=self.update_plots())

        self.stream_window.mainloop()
        self.analyse_window.mainloop()

    def update_feed(self): #updates the live stream window
        frame = self.vid.get_frame() #gets frame video object
        self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
        self.live_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tk.NW)
        self.stream_window.after(15, self.update_feed) #15 ms delay

    def update_plots(self): #updates the crop image window
        cropFrame = self.plot(self.vid.get_frame()) #gets frame from video object and crops the frame
        cropFrame_img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cropFrame)
        self.canvas_color.create_image(0, 0, image = cropFrame_img, anchor = tk.NW)
        self.stream_window.after(1500, self.update_plots) #1500 ms delay
```

When I create the application object; effectively running the above code, I get the following error.

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist
```

I know this is the error that is due to tkinter not being able to properly handle photos. The solution suggested by [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) requires using a label and an additional reference so that python does not delete the image.

For this specific case, how should I go about creating an additional reference?

Comment: Change to `self.cropFrame_img = PIL...`

Comment: Tried this, but the error remains

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the **full Traceback**